# Cannot instantiate class DataAccess because of mocking DB mapper in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jmockit

Getting errors for trying to test my data access class:

> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.datasource.DataSourceException

Test class:

```
@Tested
DataAccess dataAccess;

@Mock
Mapper mapper;
```

DataAccess class:

```
private Logger logger;

private final Mapper mapper;

public DataAccess() {
    String loggerCategory = new properties().getLoggerCategory();
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerCategory);

    mapper = DBControl.getAutoClosingMapper(
            Mapper.class, DataSource.source, logger);
}
```

DBControl (where the error is coming from):

```
private static final SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper;

static {
   Reader reader = null;
   String resource = "configuration.database.xml";
   reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);

   //the exception is getting thrown from this line
   sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
}
```

I've tried several different mockito and jmockit annotations in my test class but I am left with the same error each time.

I simply just need to mock the mapper.

Comment: I think the problem is that static block that is used in DBControl. I am not sure that this can be mocked. Maybe you can add the required xml-File in your test module.

Comment: Can you post some code from the test? you only posted two class variables.

Comment: @PhilNinan well the test class is throwing the error on initializing `DataAccess`. It's not even getting to the test. The error is the same regardless of the test that I attempt to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I noticed here, is that you are using the `@Mock` annotation to try to mock a final class variable, that typically is not going to work unless you have a constructor someplace.

e.g.

```
public class DataAccess{

   private final Mapper mapper;
   DataAccess(mapper){
    this.mapper = mapper
    // anything else
   }
}
```

Using mockito you could do something like this:

```
public class TestClass{
 private DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(Mockito.mock(Mapper.class));
}
```

Also, I would typically instantiate the Logger when you declare it;

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```